# FreeBSD 8.2 setkey null encryption

Tags: freebsd, ipsec

Anyone got progress on setting null encryption in FreeBSD 8 ipsec?

```
# ./setkey -c
add 10.10.19.50 10.10.19.100 esp 1680464666 -m transport -E null -A hmac-md5 "authentication!!" ;

The result of line 1: Invalid argument.
```

patch from [here](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2006-November/021074.html) change nothing same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved it. Let me show solution just in case someone need it.
First You need enable IPSEC in kernel, build install.

In file /src/sbin/setkey/parse.y comment code

```
enc_alg
        :       ALG_ENC_NOKEY {
                        if ($1 < 0) {
                                yyerror("unsupported algorithm");
                                return -1;
                        }
                        p_alg_enc = $1;

                        p_key_enc_len = 0;
                        p_key_enc = NULL;
                        /*
                        if (ipsec_check_keylen(SADB_EXT_SUPPORTED_ENCRYPT,
                            p_alg_enc, PFKEY_UNUNIT64(p_key_enc_len)) < 0) {
                                yyerror(ipsec_strerror());
                                return -1;
                        }
                        */
```

run make just in setkey folder. Generated binary will support null encryption.